# Is it possible to launch and record only the input of a bash session?

Tags: python, linux, shell

I am trying to achieve the following:

Have a python script launch a shell. User uses that shell for whatever purposes he needs. After having closed the shell, a log of only the input commands is available to the python script for parsing.

All I have gotten are ways to invoke the shell through popen and similar, but that's not quite what I need.

Comment: How realistic do you need that shell to be? If it doesn't need stdin to be a real TTY, this is outright trivial (`stdin=PIPE`, have your Python code read stdin, log it, and then send it on to the pipe, and there you are). If you _do_ need stdin to be a real TTY, I'd probably use pexpect to do the heavy lifting (and encourage you to come back and ask a more specific question after making a real attempt at using said tool).

Comment: The "Why not just use a pipe?" section of the pexpect FAQ @ https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/FAQ.html, by the way, goes into detail on the limits of the "doesn't need stdin to be a real TTY" case.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it needs to be an actual shell. I am basicalling trying to make a python script to record the input commands and use them to create a script library of sorts.

Comment: ...I mean, a copy of `bash` is a "real shell" even if its stdin isn't a TTY; some of the behavior is just a bit off. Anyhow, if you use my answer, your child process thinks it has a TTY, so it works completely normally.

Comment: (That said, I'm not sure what you're doing will necessarily work the way you intend -- when stdin gets handed off across programs, timing can make a difference: replay things too quickly, and the wrong program might consume content).

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, having the shell write its history to a file may be all you need. Bash lets you easily define a history file; most sites have this functionality enabled by default. Of course, it only includes the actual commands, not a precise transcript of what the user actually typed (so if they made a typo but corrected it before pressing newline, you would not know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with [`pexpect`](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect). Moreover, the examples it ships with include a [`script.py`](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/examples/script.py), which
out-of-the-box acts like the UNIX `script` command (recording both stdin and stdout), but requires only a one-line change to do what you intend:

Change `p.logfile = fout` to `p.logfile_send = fout`, and you'll be logging only data sent to the remote process; alternately, you could make it `p.logfile_recv = fout` and you would log only data received by that process.